# Get Payment Method Title of specific store

Tags: payment-methods, store-view, ce-1.9.2.2

I have a payment method instance from which I am able to get the title with

```
$sale->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle()
```

Now, I would like to get the title of this payment method as set in a specific store.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this :

```
$sale->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getConfigData('title', $storeId);
```

Where you should be having your desired store ID in `$storeId` variable.